# Set date/ time formats in a VBA to allow IF statement to work

Tags: excel, vba

In excel, I have reports that give me a column of dates (`m/d/yy` in Column A) and a column of times (`hh:mm:ss` in Column B). I have an issue with the dates being listed as the previous day if the time is before "07:00:00".  To fix this issue, I normally run an IF statement in the "C" column that says `=IF(B2<$C$1,A2+1,A2)`.  In cell "C1" I manually put in the "07:00:00" and start the IF statement at C2 and copy it down to the rest of the entries.  I also note that when I get this report in excel, the time column is set to the format of "General".

I am running into an issue trying to make this run in a macro so I do not have to take the extra time to do this (and some other) formatting.  I have gotten the IF statement into the cells I want but none of the dates that are incorrect are changing.  This seems to be because of the formatting of the times (and possibly dates?) .  I attempted to use the `.NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"` to make sure that all of the referenced and new cells were the same but there is still no change. Am I missing something to make the formats match up?  Here is a sample of the code I am using:

```
Sub Date_Change()
    Dim w1 As Worksheet
    Set w1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    w1.Range("C1").FormulaR1C1 = "07:00:00" 
    w1.Range("C1").NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
    w1.Range("A:A").NumberFormat = "m/d/yy"
    w1.Range("B:B").NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
    w1.Range("C2").Formula = "=IF(B2<$C$1,A2+1,A2)"
    w1.Range("C2").NumberFormat = "m/d/yy"
    w1.Range("C2").Select
    ActiveCell.Copy
    ActiveCell.AutoFill Destination:=Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1),
    ActiveCell.Offset(0,-1).End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 0)).Offset(0, 1)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you start C1 with,

```
w1.Range("C1") = TimeSerial(7, 0, 0)
```

... and follow up with,

```
w1.Range("C1").NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
```

That will definitively put in a correct 7:00 AM starting time (e.g. *0.291667*).

The IF formula as you have provided for C2 might be better as,

```
w1.Range("C2").Formula = "=A2 + (B2<$C$1)"
```